# set value to false if there is a duplicate

Tags: arrays, reactjs, duplicates, array.prototype.map

i don't know if there's a solution to this problem but here's what i want to do,
i have this array

```
array=[
{'id': 1, 'isActive': true, 'name': apple}, 
{'id': 2, 'isActive': false, 'name': orange},
{'id': 3, 'isActive': false, 'name': apple}, 
{'id': 4, 'isActive': false, 'name': apple}, 
{'id': 5, 'isActive': false, 'name': orange},
{'id': 6, 'isActive': false, 'name': forest}
{'id': 7, 'isActive': false, 'name': forest}
]
```

i want to map through this array but i only want to show the array without duplicates but without changing the array ! i was thinking about adding another value so it will be like this

```
array=[
{'id': 1, 'isActive': true, 'name': apple, 'isShown': true}, 
{'id': 2, 'isActive': false, 'name': orange, 'isShown': true},
{'id': 3, 'isActive': false, 'name': apple, 'isShown': false}, 
{'id': 4, 'isActive': false, 'name': apple, 'isShown': false}, 
{'id': 5, 'isActive': false, 'name': orange, 'isShown': false},
{'id': 6, 'isActive': false, 'name': forest, 'isShown': true},
{'id': 7, 'isActive': false, 'name': forest, 'isShown': false},
]
```

I thought about this but i didn't know how to do it :x Any help or tips ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You said "array without duplicates" and later "but without changing the array"... in your expected result you show  the array with duplicates. Also, why `id:3` and `id:4` has `isShow: false`? (apple exists on the list). Whats the criteria to assign `isShown` value?

Comment: i thought it was clear, okay, the array must stay as it is without deleting the duplicates, but when i map through that array, i don't want to show the duplicated objects, i thought of adding a new value which is isShown that gets 'true' for the first value and 'false' to the duplicated values, i don't know if this is clear

Comment: Feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to add another prop if all that is needed is to avoid "showing" duplicates? Why can't one simply create a copy of this array which doesn't have the dupes - that way, the array remains as-is and another one without duplicates is handy when one needs to "show" without dupes.

Comment: Anyhoo, please try this: `console.log(array.map(({name, ...rest}, idx) => ({...rest, name, isShown: (idx === array.findIndex(ob => ob.name === name))})));` and share your feedback. This is not an answer; only a comment. If it works and / or have any question/s, an answer can be added, later (if required).

Comment: @jsN00b Cause i might need to show this duplicates or some of them later ( with an onClick or smth ), so if i have the isShown Prop it will help in showing the values later and thank you

Comment: @jsN00b Your solution is working perfectly! thank you! sorry i couldn't explain it better in the questions :x